# How to insert value to the text box using Ajax from the Drop Down Menu?The Result should be come on the Form Texbox How?

Tags: php, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showUser(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        }
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else { // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                //document.myForm.text1.value=.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "getuser.php?q=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>

</head>

<body>
<form name="myForm">
    <p>Selec the Menu :
        <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
            <option value="">Select ID</option>
<?php do { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row_rscustomer['customer_number']?>"><?php echo $row_rscustomer['customer_number']?></option>
<?php } while ($row_rscustomer = mysql_fetch_assoc($rscustomer));
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($rscustomer);
        if ($rows > 0) {
            mysql_data_seek($rscustomer, 0);
            $row_rscustomer = mysql_fetch_assoc($rscustomer);
        } ?>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>
        <input name="text1" type="text"
               value="<?php include (" getuser.php");?>"/>
    <p>
</form>
<div id="txtHint"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hey - I noticed that, inside your AJAX onreadystatechange function, you have added xmlhttp.status==200 to your conditional.  In some browsers, as AJAX is a client-side language, this isn't supported.  If the member *status* isn't supported by the user's browser, then its default value will either be *undefined* or 0, either way the value will never be 200, thus the block inside that conditional won't be executed.

I suggest removing the *xmlhttp.status==200* condition, and just relying on *xmlhttp.readyState*.  I had this problem when I first started with AJAX.